# Regex with constraints, look-ahead function

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex expression between 10 and 12 digits. There will be optional leading 0 (zeros) between {0,5} then a numeric string between 10-12 digits. Regardless of the number of zeros (0 to 5), I want 10-12 digits after leading zeros

Example:

```
0000012345 should not be passing 
0012345678 should not be passing as there are only 8 digits after leading zeros
```

I've tried:

```
^(0{0,5}(?=\d{10,12}$)^\d{1,2}?\s?(\d{10})$
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: I have a question. Why is `\s` there?

Comment: Trying to validate my codes at regexplanet.com (any regex engine). There is an optional space with \s so it could 12 1234567890 or 121234567890

Comment: Your specification above does not mention spaces, or a need for a look ahead. Can you give more examples, or state more stringently what your requirement are?

Comment: Can space be there at any position?

Comment: Why should it match `0000123456` but fails on `0012345678`?

Answer (score 0):

```
^0{0,5}+\d{0,2}\s?\d{10}$

       ^^
```

You didn't specify the language. You need "possessive quantifier" here.

See demo:

https://regex101.com/r/m5sOAJ/1

Or if your regex does not support possessive quantifiers:

```
^(?=(0{0,5}))\1\d{0,2}\s?\d{10}$
```

See demo:

https://regex101.com/r/m5sOAJ/3

Comment: 0000012345678.. it will fail on this

Comment: @tomsam it wont fail with the above regex

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
^0{0,5}[1-9]\d{9,11}$
```

should be what you need. It enforces not counting the leading zeroes as one of the later digits by requiring it be non-zero. Then there can be 9-11 other digits (including 0).

If you need to include an optional space at any point (as suggested by your RegEx), the RegEx would grow a lot, and it might be easier to do this with some additional code. However, if you give the exact requirements, I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think it partially works with no space option, let me try a few things on this. will get back to you. Thanks